# Securing your virtual machine

Tags: virus

I am using my virtual machine and run there a few programs that may be malicious. Is there a risk of my host getting infected?
Can a virus migrate to my host considering that I dont allow file sharing and clipboard pasting..

Do I need to use programs like deep freeze, anti viruses, firewalls to protect the guest machine from invading my host machine?

Comment: It isnt a duplicate, I was researching and I saw that thread. I am here to get practical help. Not theoretical thoughts

Comment: It sounds like in that case you're actually asking for product recommendations, which are also off topic for this site, unfortunately.

Comment: What product recommendation. I am asking on how to secure the network, because both devices work under the same registry..and the virtual box file is sitting on my host. I am asking how to secure my system. I will be running many malicious programs on my guest machine. I dont want to discover that my host got infected.

Comment: This question is far too broad for practical advice. Not that there is much practical advice to give. That other thread does answer “Can a virus migrate to my host”, and disabling ways of communication like file and clipboard sharing takes care of the main threat anyway.